# Recursively print diamond in python

Tags: python, printing, recursion, python-3.x

Can anyone help me out here, I am stuck on the base cases for turning this code into a recursive function... Can't use loops in the recursive function obviously.

```
def diamond(a):

assert a > 0, "width must be greater than zero"


for i in range(0, a, 2):

    for c in range(0, a - i, 2):
        print(" ", end='')

    if a % 2 == 0:
        i += 1

    for m in range(0, i - 1):
        print("*", end='')

    print()


for i in range (0, a, 2):

    for c in range(0, i, 2):
        print(" ", end='')

    for m in range(0, a - i):
        print("*", end='')

    print()
```

Comment: Figuring out the base cases is half the recursion. What do you have so far?

Comment: Your code is misformatted. Also, don't leave a space after the start of a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because this must be homework, I won't give you the code, but explain how to do it in  words:

Instead of looping, you make a function that calls itself, and passes the variables you need as parameters. Then you have a test with an "if" in the function that when true, stops the looping and instead returns. That was you will then "fall" out of the loop.

So in this case you would pass in `a` and `i` as parameters, increase `i` with one in the function, and when `i` is greater than `a`, just `return`.

Comment: Lennart, we are not allowed to change the amount of parameters that the function takes.

Comment: @user1550365 Then create another function.

Comment: pretty sure there is no way to do this with only the original width as the first argument i think you need to use a default optional second parameter

Comment: @user1550365: What Marcin said. Remember that you also in Python can create functions within functions as well. But I would create a default optional second parameter `i=0` (or `level=0` might be a better name), and while that adds a parameter, you can still call it with only one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def triangles(n):
     if not n & 1:
         raise ValueError('n must be odd')
    print_diamond(0, n, n >> 1)

def print_diamond(start, stop, midpoint):
    if start < stop:
        if start <= midpoint:
            print('  ' * (midpoint - start) + '* ' * ((start << 1) + 1))
        else:
            print('  ' * (start - midpoint) + '* ' * ((stop - start << 1) - 1))
        print_diamond(start + 1, stop, midpoint)

triangles(5)
```